# Suppose that any broker trading in both financial assets A and B is a money launderer operating from country C.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science

Suppose that any broker trading in both financial assets A and B is a money
launderer operating from country C.
Is statement "Any money launderer not operating from country C does not trades in asset A or does not trades in asset B" true or false ?

My idea is let say A, B, C and D (money launderer), the first statement implies A and B implies C and D. So not (C and D) can implies not (A and B) which means not C or not D implies not A or not B. For me, it's correct but i need a second opinion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: That iscorrect.

Comment: let say A, B, C and D (money launderer), the first statement implies A and B implies C and D. So not (C and D) can implies not (A and B) which means not C or not D implies not A or not B. For me, it's correct but i need a second opinion.